# A subquery with the ALL operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a SQL (Postgres engine) query that answers the following question:

*Which countries have a GDP greater than every country in Asia? [Give the name only.] (Some countries may have NULL gdp values)*

**Below is an abbreviated SQL table containing sample data.**

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
|    name     | continent |  area   | population |     gdp      |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| Afghanistan | Asia      |  652230 |   25500100 |  20343000000 |
| Albania     | Europe    |   28748 |    2831741 |  12960000000 |
| Algeria     | Africa    | 2381741 |   37100000 | 188681000000 |
| Andorra     | Europe    |     468 |      78115 |   3712000000 |
| Angola      | Africa    | 1246700 |   20609294 | 100990000000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

I wrote something like the following, which returns nothing (although I know this isn't the answer due to the online interactive guide I'm using):

```
SELECT name
FROM  world
WHERE gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp from world WHERE continent = 'Asia')
AND   continent<>'Asia'
```

What query should I use?  I'm pretty new to SQL.

Comment: What did you do to address your "*Some countries may have NULL gdp values*" requirement?

Comment: I didn't, I assumed NULL values would be treated as zeros by the combination of the "greater than" and ALL operators...I'm new to SQL.

Comment: `NULL` is **not** equal to anything (including another `NULL`), **not** larger than anything, and **not** smaller than anything. If 'Asia' has at least one country with `NULL` as `gdp` your existing condition will fail.

Comment: While you can use `> ALL` here, `max` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Unless this is a specific exercise on `ALL` with `nullable` fields (SQL Zoo has those).

Comment: Thanks everyone,as it turns out, it might have been a bit of a trick question as right above the question it talks about using ALL to allow <= or >= to act over a list.  But *SELECT name FROM world WHERE gdp > (SELECT MAX(gdp) from world WHERE continent = 'Asia') AND continent<>'Asia'* seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, if there is a single Asian country in your table with an unknown (`NULL`) GDP, then the correct answer must be:

*"We do not know."*

Accordingly, this query returns no row:

```
SELECT name
FROM   world
WHERE  gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp from world WHERE continent = 'Asia')
AND    continent <> 'Asia';
```

A NULL value in the set of Asian GDP's makes it impossible for the first `WHERE` expression to be `TRUE`, so the query can never return rows - which is the correct answer. There is no country that we *know* to fit the requirement.  The query you had is ***correct***.

The variant you squeezed [into a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667528/a-subquery-with-the-all-operator/26670203#comment41936872_26667528) comparing to `max(gdp)` answers a slightly different question:

*Which countries have a GDP greater than the greatest known GDP in Asia?*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the sum of all Asian countries.  If so, try something like this:

```
select w1.name 
from world w1 
where w1.gdp > (
   select sum(coalesce(w2.gdp,0)) 
   from world w2 
   where w2.continent='Asia' )
```

If not, and you want just the single Asian country with the highest GDP, replace `sum` with `max`. You don't need the additional `continent <> 'Asia'` because no Asian country can have a higher GDP than the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tony 's answer, it should be like this:

```
  select w1.name 
  from world w1 
  where w1.gdp > (
    select max(coalesce(w2.gdp,0)) 
    from world w2 
    where w2.continent='Asia' ) 
  and w2.gdp is not null;
```

Why use `max` instead of `sum`? Because the question asked:

> Which countries have a GDP greater than every country in Asia?

So finding the largest gdp in Asia will work and you don't have to compare with all of the countries in Asia.

I am sorry I can't comment on @Tony 's answer since my reputation is under 50.

Comment: I believe I said all that in my answer. :P